# Firebase Google Authentication with EXPO React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-oauth

How should I implement firebase Google authentication with my React Native app?

Most of the packages I tried were deprecated. E.G. "expo-google-app-auth"

I tried multiple packages and ways and all of them were sadly deprecated or outdated.